# substring in string in nim (in operator)

Tags: substring, nim-lang

I wanted to verify substring existence in a string and came up with:
`if "haystack".find("needle") != -1:`

But I would have prefered:
`if "needle" in "haystack":` as in python.
Though we get:

> Error: type mismatch: got (string, string) but expected one of:  proc
>   contains[T](s: Slice[T]; value: T): bool proc contains[T](x: set[T];
>   y: T): bool proc contains[T](a: openArray[T]; item: T): bool

*note that if you `import strutils` it starts to work.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already gave the answer yourself, `import strutils` to get the `contains` proc for strings. Nim automatically used the `contains` proc for the `in` operator.

Comment: Ok, just wanted a bit more depth out of it, because one would think, an operator is a language keyword. But in this case it is a proc that gets called after a remap of `in` to `contains` that's convoluted. Also I'm just posting tons of basic questions to make google useful for nim. Right now it's the desert, nim is unusable because of how google is unhelpful with basic questions.